# Pandas workbook/spreadsheet math to find missing data?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I'm picking up someone else's work on some workbook manipulation and math and I've never used Pandas before.  They had a workbook with 2 sheets, combined them to "dataframes" then did a concat and drop duplicates giving a list of only what's unique, works great.  Step 2, they used some comparisons to pull out some rows based on cell values which basically left 5 separate sheets of data:

Unique_Data

- Fixable_Data
- Removeable_Data
- Severity_Changed
- New_Data

  In theory the bottom 4 should add up to the first, but there are about 80 rows missing somewhere.

  I need a simple way to add them all into 1 again, then re-unique them so I can try and figure out what's left ( 6th sheet ).  I'm reading the pandas docs and slowly starting to understand it, but I'm not seeing something this simple in simple terms or I've over looked it.

Any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the 4 dataframes you want to concat in a list then use `pd.concat()` to join them. Once you have the concatenated dataframe you can get the unique values by dropping duplicates.

```
df_list = [Fixable_Data, Removeable_Data, Severity_Changed, New_Data] 
new_df = pd.concat(df_list)
new_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I did, but don't have enough rep for it to show, but "it's recorded", but thats why I responded it worked.  I don't post often enough to get the rep apparantly.